# Most efficient way to read from bottom of Azure Table Storage

Tags: azure, azure-table-storage

I have a an Azure table which serves as an event log. I need the most efficient way to read the bottom of the table to retrieve the most recent entries.

What is the most efficient way of doing this?

Comment: How have you defined PartitionKey and RowKey values in this table?

Comment: @GauravMantri, yes indeed I have.

Comment: Sorry, I was not clear in my question above. What I wanted to ask was about the logic you have used to define the keys. For example, if you take a look at diagnostics data collected by cloud services they use DateTime.Ticks (in UTC) up to minutes precision for PartitionKey.

Comment: @GauravMantri Sure. For my event log the partition key is the month / year formatted as YY-MM and the row key is DateTime.UtcNow + a GUID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, I would really advice you to base your partition key on UTC ticks. You can do it in a way that all the antities are ordered from latest to oldest.

Then if you want to get lets say 100 latest logs you just call (lets say that query is IQueryable something from your favorite client - we use Lucifure Stash): query.Take(100);

If you want to fetch entities for certain period you write: query.Where(x => x.PartitionKey <= value); or something similar.

The "value" variable has to be constructed based on the way you construct the values for partition key.

Comment: Great suggestion and did exactly what I wanted to do.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to fetch the data for last 15 minutes, try this pseudo code:

```
    DateTime toDateTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
    DateTime fromDateTime = toDateTime.AddMinutes(-15);

    string myPartitionKeyFrom = fromDateTime.ToString("yy-MM");
    string myPartitionKeyTo = toDateTime.ToString("yy-MM");

    string query = "";
    if (myPartitionKeyFrom.Equals(myPartitionKeyTo))//In case both time periods fall in same month, then we can directly hit that partition.
    {
        query += "(PartitionKey eq '" + myPartitionKeyFrom + "') ";
    }
    else // Otherwise we would need to do a greater than and lesser than stuff.
    {
        query += "(PartitionKey ge '" + myPartitionKeyFrom + "' and PartitionKey le '" + myPartitionKeyTo + "') ";
    }
    query += "and (RowKey ge '" + fromDateTime.ToString() + "' and RowKey le '" + toDateTime.ToString() + "')";
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to fetch latest 'n' number of entries then you need to slightly modify your PartitionKey and RowKey value, So that latest entries will be pushed to the top of the table.

For this you need to compute both the keys using `DateTime.MaxValue.Subtract(DateTime.UtcNow).Ticks;` instead of DateTime.UtcNow.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft provides a [SemanticLogging](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EnterpriseLibrary.SemanticLogging/) framework that has a specific sink to [log to Azure Table](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EnterpriseLibrary.SemanticLogging.WindowsAzure/).

If you look at the library code, it generates a partition key (in reverse order) based on a Datetime :

```
static string GeneratePartitionKeyReversed(DateTime dateTime)
{
    dateTime = dateTime.AddMinutes(-1.0);
    return GetTicksReversed(
        new DateTime(dateTime.Year, dateTime.Month, dateTime.Day, dateTime.Hour, dateTime.Minute, 0));
}

static string GetTicksReversed(DateTime dateTime)
{
    return (DateTime.MaxValue - dateTime.ToUniversalTime())
        .Ticks.ToString("d19", (IFormatProvider)CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
}
```

So you can implement the same logic in your application to build your partitionkey.

If you want to retrieve the logs for a specific date range, you can write a query that looks like that:

```
var minDate = GeneratePartitionKeyReversed(DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(-2));
var maxDate = GeneratePartitionKeyReversed(DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(-1));

// Get the cloud table
 var cloudTable = GetCloudTable();

// Build the query
IQueryable<DynamicTableEntity> query = cloudTable.CreateQuery<DynamicTableEntity>();

// condition for max date
query = query.Where(a => string.Compare(a.PartitionKey, maxDate,
                            StringComparison.Ordinal) >= 0);

// condition for min date
query = query.Where(a => string.Compare(a.PartitionKey, minDate,
                            StringComparison.Ordinal) <= 0);3
```